# Can experimental features like offscreenanvas be enabled in electron?

Tags: electron

A 2d or webgl canvas rendered using [OffscreenCanvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/ro/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas) could have some interesting performance benefits. I'm wondering if there is a way to enable it in the latest electron.

Setting the experimentalFeatures flag as discussed in this thread did not work.

The following console logs:

```
console.log('canvasNode', canvasNode)
console.log('transferControlToOffscreen', canvasNode.transferControlToOffscreen)
console.log('OffscreenCanvas', window.OffscreenCanvas)
```

Output this results:

[image: console output]

And the way I am instantiating the browser window which logs this is:

```
win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1200,
    height: 700,
    webPreferences: { experimentalFeatures: true }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two links and a google later I found the answer on this [github doc page](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md)

Since the offscreencanvas is a canvas related feature it is under a different flag called `experimentalCanvasFeatures`

In order to enable it I had to instantiate my browser window like so:

```
win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1200,
    height: 700,
    webPreferences: { experimentalCanvasFeatures: true }
})
```

With `experimentalCanvasFeatures` instead of `experimentalFeatures`.

This resulted in the following console output:

[image]